# Is the identity matrix and its multiples always commutative?

Tags: matrices

Is the identity matrix \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} and its scalar multiples always commutative?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity matrix commutes with all matrices since $IM = MI = M$. Now, numbers can be shifted around as you please, so that if $K = rI$, we have that $KM - MK = r(IM - MI) = 0$.

Comment: And multiples of the identity matrix are also commutative?

Comment: Every matrix is a multiple of the identity matrix, so no.

Comment: @AJY I think it means a scalar multiple, in which case yes

Comment: @Daminark Yes, I meant scalar multiples of the identity matrix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and you can write any matrix as an addition of elementary matrices.